I can't access Pynq Z2 via browser after altering jupyter_notebook_config.py
I am using the Pynq Z2 board to code a project. I have been accessing the Jupyter Notebook by connecting the board to a router that my PC is also connected to by LAN-cable. I used to be able to access it by using the address "http://pynq:9090/".
But yesterday I altered the file jupyter_notebook_config.py so I could send data from my PC to the Jupyter Notebook. I altered it with the following steps:

I typed "jupyter notebook --generate-config" in a terminal

I opened the file jupyter_notebook_config.py which was located in "/home/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py"

I added the lines "c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'" and "c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'"

I ran the following in the terminal: "sudo ufw allow 8888"


After doing this I was able to send strings from my PC to the Jupyter Notebook using sockets. But when I try to access the Notebook today the connection simply fails.
I have tried to write different ports like 8888 in the hope of accessing the Jupyter Notebook, but without success.
I have also tried to connect the Pynq Z2 LAN-cable directly to my computer and assign it a static IP address, but the attempt to access still failed.
I don't know what exactly I did wrong and how I can fix it. Could someone please give me help?
Update: After having no success with connecting to the Jupyter Notebook as is I made the somewhat drastic step of flashing a new image to the SD card. This reset all files, including the config file that I changed, but I did lose some work. Should I leave this question up or should it be marked as answered now?
